# Error building with OpenCV Dependency

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build a package on Electric that uses OpenCV but I am getting an error saying I don't have OpenCV 2.3.2. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone give me some pointers. Here is the error I recieve when running rosmake on my package.

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package cv_bridge
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "OpenCV" that is compatible
  with requested version "2.3.2".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /usr/share/OpenCV-2.3.1/OpenCVConfig.cmake, version: 2.3.1



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32155/error-building-with-opencv-dependency/) by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mouser58907](https://answers.ros.org/users/1327/mouser58907/) on 2012-04-19**:
Kevin, There is nothing in the CMakeLists.txt file, but the manifest.xml has "" I just made a new package with the dependencies I need and tried to make it. I haven't put any real code into it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are you building? :) A quick check of opencv says 2.3.1 is the current version out and 2.4 Beta is out. I haven't heard of 2.3.2 before. What does the CMakeLists.txt file say ... find_package(OpenCV 2.3.1 REQUIRED)? If it says 2.3.2 then try changing that to 2.3.1 and do a "make clean" first.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0